# Regular expression re2 grouping (and/or operators)

Tags: regex, looker-studio, re2

I'm struggling to get the right regular expression for grouping ranges of latitudes and longitudes. I'm using Google Data Studio filters that use re2 I believe. These are given in the URL, so i'm trying to filter out only lat/lon pairs that are in an irregular shaped domain I'm interested in.  If it was a square domain, I can do this easily because there's one group of lat that correspond with one group of lon.

Here's what I want to do:

```
If latitude is in this range: Latitude 39\.[4-9]|Latitude 40\.[0-9]|Latitude 41\.[0-5]  AND longitude is in this range: Longitude 80\.[0-5]|Longitude 79\.[0-9]  (then capture these URLs)
```

OR if

```
latitude is in this range: Latitude 40\.[0-7]|Latitude 39\.[6-9] AND longitude in this range: Longitude 82\.[2-9]|Longitude 81\.[0-9]|Longitude 80\.[0-5] (then capture these URLs)
```

Here's how it feels I should be able to do it, but the syntax doesn't work:

```
((Latitude 39\.[4-9]|Latitude 40\.[0-9]|Latitude 41\.[0-5]) & (Longitude 80\.[0-5]|Longitude 79\.[0-9]))|((Latitude 40\.[0-7]|Latitude 39\.[6-9])&(Longitude 82\.[2-9]|Longitude 81\.[0-9]|Longitude 80\.[0-5]))
```

I know data studio regex can use the pipe/or symbol, but I really need the &/and symbol to make this work, but I don't think I can use that symbol.

I've tried a lot of different combinations, but I can't quite get it right in the Data Studio Filters. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Can you give an example of the format of input to match, please?

Comment: Sure, here's an example of the URL title (filtering by page title) that I'm trying to group, pending lat/lon.  "Forecast for Latitude 42.36(degree symbol)N and Longitude 122.95(degrees symbol)W".  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out. I needed to combine the latitude and longitude into one regular expression, and then use Google's Data Studio options to use "or", and then put in the next expression.

Here are the two expressions, and they account for the second decimal point for latitude and longitude (if exists) via the .{2,3} part.

```
.+for Latitude (39\.[4-9]|40\.[0-9]|41\.[0-5]).{2,3} and Longitude (80\.[0-5]|79\.[0-9]).+

.+for Latitude (40\.[0-7]|39\.[6-9]).{2,3} and Longitude (82\.[2-9]|81\.[0-9]|80\.[0-5]).+
```